# Antd: set default value / setFieldsValue for Cascader when opening Modal

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have Antd's Cascader like this:

When I click on Edit button it open modal as below.

```
  const showModal = (record) => {
    console.log('record', record); // this is current record which has existing value to be displayed in cascader
    form.setFieldsValue(record);
    setVisible(true);
  };
```

how do I feed initial values or existing values to Cascader?

```
 <Cascader
defaultValue={['zhejiang', 'hangzhou', 'xihu']}
              options={propertyOptions}
              loadData={loadCompanies}
              onChange={onChange}
              changeOnSelect
            />
```

using `defaultValue` prop like does not seem to work.

When I load propertyOptions, it loads with values like

```
property1,
property2
```

When I click on property1 it loads children dynamically.

so selected value is e.g. property1 > company1

but When I click on Edit modal it has only parent values. (children won't be there as I load them on parent click).

When I click on modal it has the whole item data so maybe I can use it to show like hardcoded value or something?

UPDATE:

This is how I fill propertyOptions

```
function setPropertiesAsOptions(propertiesQuerySnapshot) {
  propertiesQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    options.push({
      value: doc.id,
      label: doc.data().propertyName,
      isLeaf: false,
    });
  });
  setPropertyOptions(options);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your properly1 and property2 look like? Also what is edit modal? Is it new modal or about situation when you edit modal?)

Comment: I updated the question. also Edit modal meaning its editing data. so existing selected values should be pre-populated in this cascader

Answer (score 0):

Is there propertyOptions has value names like `zhejiang` or other? 
In your case this data should work properly as options

> `const options = [
>     {
>       value: 'zhejiang',
>       label: 'Zhejiang',
>       children: [
>         {
>           value: 'hangzhou',
>           label: 'Hangzhou',
>           children: [
>             {
>               value: 'xihu',
>               label: 'West Lake',
>             },
>           ],
>         },
>       ],
>     },
>     {
>       value: 'jiangsu',
>       label: 'Jiangsu',
>       children: [
>         {
>           value: 'nanjing',
>           label: 'Nanjing',
>           children: [
>             {
>               value: 'zhonghuamen',
>               label: 'Zhong Hua Men',
>             },
>           ],
>         },
>       ],
>     },
>   ];`

So it's mean that value name should be the same as params in defaultValue

Comment: I've updated question with some details. please have a look

Comment: propertyOptions has different value names than example. I am concern is how do I fill them from the record on Edit modal click? (using setFieldsValue ?)